# Let $X, Y$ be random variables which are not independtent and whose distribution we know. How can we find distribution of $XY$?

Tags: probability

Let $X, Y$ be random variables which are not independent and whose distribution we know. 
How can we find distribution of $XY$?

Comment: I don't think it's always possible, but you can regard it as a factor of a two-dimensional distribution and see if you can find that one.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta thanks :)

Comment: If there is no independence then knowledge of the marginals is not enough to find the distribution of $XY$ (or more generally functions $f(X,Y)$ where both arguments are not dummy). What you really need is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. In the special case of independence the joint distribution is determined by the marginal distributions.